# Есть ли стилистическая ошибка в фразе?

Tags: стилистика

Мне кажется, в этой фразе есть стилистическая ошибка: я не хочу "многого". Или "Я не хочу много! Я хочу всё!" - верно?

Answer (score 3):

> Есть ли стилистическая ошибка в фразе?
>
> "Я не хочу много! Я хочу всё!"

К примеру, вот в таком контексте

> *-- Ты много хочешь!*
>
> *-- Я не хочу "много"! Я хочу всё!*

я стилистической ошибки не вижу.

Comment: Фраза без контекста (в виде отдельной реплики, статуса). 
Является ли стилистически верной в форме "Я не хочу много! Я хочу всё"?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Я не хочу много! Я хочу всё!

Многое (от многий, склоняется) - о том, что является значительным ПО КОЛИЧЕСТВУ, содержанию (это ряд предметов). Говорить о многом. Быть многим обязанным родителям. М. забывается в старости. Оставляет желать многого.

Много - нареч. (не склоняется)  В большом количестве, в значительной степени; не мало (это большой объем, большая интенсивность действия). Больше, чем нужно, чем следует, чем хотелось бы кому-л. Кто-л. много говорит. М. запросить за товар. Ребёнок м. шумит. Слишком МНОГО хотеть.